# Synchronise local database cache with a condition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola

To synchronize data between my handheld app and a back end app, I'm using a WCF service library together with a local database cache (as described [here](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2008/12/08/building-a-sync-services-for-ado-net-solution-for-mobile-devices.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882690.aspx)).

The synchronization works.

A user of a handheld only needs a subset of the data. However, when setting up the local database cache, I can only select an entire table to sync (and all new incremental data from the back end is pulled to the handheld).

Is it possible to add a condition to the synchronization, e.g. only select routes assigned to the user-of-handheld ? Perhaps the local database cache has this feature but I have not found it.

Alternative solutions:

1. I've looked at the generated .cs files and saw the SQL. Perhaps I could modify that SQL to include a parameter? But it feels like a hack.
2. Alternatively I could just write my own WCF service that has a user parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also can try SQL Server publication services where you can add some conditional synchronization